# Why the FirstOrDefault search on IEnumerable<Row> based on RowIndex doesn't work in debug windows?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, openxml, watch, immediate-window

The below line of code, which does a FirstOrDefault search on IEnumerable based on RowIndex doesn't work in debug windows (in Watch,Quick watch and Immediate window). It throws a System.NullReferenceException in these windows. I'm using Visual studio 2015 update 3.

```
sheetdata.Descendants<Row>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.RowIndex.Value == 2U)
```

But when I convert it to list and do the same search it works in these debug windows. Why is this discrepancy?

```
sheetdata.Descendants<Row>().ToList().FirstOrDefault(p => p.RowIndex.Value == 2U)
```

This discrepancy is not there when I run the code. I can see this discrepancy only when I try to debug the code in these debug windows.

[image]

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't describe what you're seeing at all. Please clarify, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `Convert.ToUInt32(2))` Jeez.  `2u`

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. I updated the question by avoiding the convert.

Answer (score 3):

I think the QueryProvider of OpenXml has a problem with handling of `Convert.ToUInt32(2)`, cause he needs to translate that into its own language (like a QueryProvider for SQL).

You should try to avoid converts in predicates and do them upfront, cause not all QueryProviders support all functionalities and might throw exceptions (mostly `NotSupportedException`).

```
uint value = Convert.ToUInt32(2);
sheetdata.Descendants<Row>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.RowIndex.Value == value)
```

The call `.ToList()` will perform this in memory, cause it will read all values from your sheet and then finds the first matching value.

Comment: You can write the value two of type `uint` as just `2u` and use that directly. The C# compiler and any Linq provider will know much better what `2u` is, compared to the method invocation `Convert.ToUInt32(2)` which they may not realize the meaning of. Besides, in the context of an operand to `==`, you can just use `2` because the C# compiler will be smart enough to choose the proper type anyway. But `2u` is more precise for the human reader.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this doesn't resolve the issue. I updated the question by avoiding the convert.